# Use of addTextChangedListener inside adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm using a list adapter to load data to my list view. I have used `addTextChangedListener` in my adapter and I'm getting 2 errors. Can anyone help me to correct those 2 errors. 
I have used this code inside ActivitySearchResults then it worked but I want to use this code inside the adapter.

**UPDATED**

java code

```
        public class CustomListSearch extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private final List<String> descriptions;
    private final List<String> menudescriptions;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    EditText inputSearch;

    public CustomListSearch(Context c, List<String> descriptions,
            List<String> menudescriptions) {
        this.context = c;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.menudescriptions = menudescriptions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return descriptions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return descriptions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private EditText inputSearch;
        private TextView tvMenudescriptions;
        private TextView tvDescriptions;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.tvDescriptions = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            holder.tvMenudescriptions = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.product_description);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvDescriptions.setText(descriptions.get(position));
        holder.tvMenudescriptions.setText(menudescriptions.get(position));

        holder.inputSearch = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { // null point
                                                    // exception
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

    private void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I have commented the errors in my code. Can u check the comments I have added in my code please

Comment: I have updated my question, now I'm getting an null point exception. I have shown that point in using a comment. you got any idea why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this inside if(convertView == null)

```
inputSearch = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
```

And make convertView **final** in getView parameters..

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position,final View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: I have removed the complete code, I have updated my question, now I'm getting an null point exception. I have shown that point in using a comment. you got any idea why is that?

Comment: Why don't you put inputSearch in the ViewHolder and follow my answer?

Comment: Can't make it final because I'm getting an error in this line. convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);

Comment: Write View = convertView; and then check if the view is null

Comment: I have updated my code, now it doesn't crash. it loads all the data. But addTextChangedListener function doesn't work